Multiple Consumer widgets using a common widget
I am relatively new to Flutter. I am having a row of Consumer widgets. I need to show a popup dialog(which I have already developed) but I want it in a way that when I right click each time on a widget ,the same instance should get shown and updated. I need one common popup dialog widget which can open upon right clicking on any one of the widgets. Currently I have one popup for one Consumer and I do not know the state of previously opened popup and unable to close the last instance before opening a new one.
I am trying to use one provider widget to be used across multiple consumers but a bit confused on the approach.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! In what way is your code not working as expected? Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done, and you can read the official provider package documentation for the references. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the tour and read How to Ask and its linked resources.

Create a common class for dialog box, then pass parameters if you want to give different data , function values...etc in that dialog.
You can call this common class wherever you want this dialog in your project with parameter values.
Check this example for reference:
   void ExitDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return    ExitDialog(
          subHeading: "Are you sure you want to exit app ?",
          buttonName: "Exit",
          onTap: () {
            SystemNavigator.pop();
          },
          onCancelTap: () {
            return Get.back(result: false);
          },
        );
        });
  }

Set your common dialog class and call the function in your button widget whenever want to pop up a dialog.

Thanks. I did create a common dataprovider which updates data to the common dialog based on the selected consumer row.Will add a snip of my solution shortly.
